# Functional Opposite of Subtract by Key

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have two RDDs of the form RDD1[K, V1] and RDD2[K, V2]. I was hoping to remove values in RDD2 which are not in RDD1. (Essentially an inner join on each of the RDD's keys, but I don't want to copy over RDD1's values.)

I understand that there's a method `subtractByKey` which performs the opposite of this. (Keeps those that are distinct.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot avoid having some type of value here so applying `join` and mapping values seems to be the way to go. You can use:

```
rdd2.join(rdd1.mapValues(_ => None)).mapValues(_._1)
```

which replaces values with dummies (usually you can skip that because there is not much to gain here unless values are largish):

```
_.mapValues(_ => None)
```

joins, and drops placeholders:

```
_.mapValues(_._1)
```